# Cosa vuol dire "fare la parte" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Lo scalpiccio non pareva precedermi di gran tratto, sebbene
>   potesse in ciò ingannarmi la suddetta eco, e, se mi fermavo, si faceva meno frequente, per arrestarsi poco dopo del tutto; se procedevo, serrava il ritmo. Esso era inoltre alquanto vario, **fatta anche
>   la parte** al rimbombo e alla natura del terreno; quasi la persona
>   corresse, come dire?, con una certa volubilità.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "fare la parte" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato alla voce "parte" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato che "fare la parte" può significare interpretare un personaggio o assumere un ruolo, ma questo non sembra avere senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato.

Comment: "Fare la parte" in alcuni contesti locali può anche voler significare "rimproverare pesantemente", ma in questo contesto non c'entra nulla.

Comment: secondo me può essere perifrasato con: "tenendo in considerazione anche la parte dovuta al rimbombo"

Answer (score 3):

Mi sembra che significhi "tenendo conto" (non è una forma moderna):

```
fatta anche la parte al rimbombo e alla natura del terreno
```

ovvero, il rumore era "alquanto vario", e questo anche **tenendo conto** della natura del terreno. Il terreno giustificava una certa variabilità del suono, ma non tutto; anche così, il suono originale era ugualmente "vario" in intensità.

**Fare la parte** in italiano moderno (anche *fare una parte*, *fare una partaccia*) significa *rimproverare*. Viene dal "fare la parte", ossia dividere le spoglie, il bottino, o simili in un gruppo, a seconda del ruolo di ciascuno ("la parte di un ufficiale", "la parte di un marinaio scelto è doppia...", ecc.):

> *- Quanto avete disegnato spendere intorno a questa impresa?*
>
> *- Ma! Non ti parrebbe abbastanza un cinquecento ducati?*
>
> *- No, signore, non bastano. **Fatta la parte ai compagni**, levate le spese dei cavalli e delle armi, mi riviene una miseria.*
>   (F. Domenico Guerrazzi, [*Beatrice Cènci*](https://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/g/guerrazzi/beatrice_cenci_storia_del_secolo_xvi/pdf/beatri_p.pdf), cap. III)

Da qui deriva anche «tenendo conto» (cioè, dando la giusta parte a qualcosa):

> Ma, **fatta la parte** a ciò che vi ha d'ingenuo in quella credenza (che è riapparsa più volte nell'estetica e nella critica d'arte), bisogna **far la parte** a quel che vi ha di profondo: al pensiero che...
>   (Benedetto Croce, [*Leonardo Filosofo*](http://www.franuvolo.it/sito/doc/Leonardo-in/016.pdf), conferenza, 1906)

Comment: A orecchio, suona anche a me così, ma me ne sentirei più sicuro se trovassimo, per esempio, altri testi letterari in cui viene usato nello stesso modo.

Comment: Ottimo, e aggiungerei anche quello che viene subito dopo:

Ma, fatta la parte a  ciò che vi ha d'ingenuo in quella credenza (che è riapparsa più volte nell'estetica e nella critica d'arte), bisogna far la parte a quel che vi ha di profondo: al pensiero che...

Comment: Quindi, più o meno sarebbe come dire, "scontando la parte del rumore dovuta al rimbombo e alla natura del terreno" nel senso che c'era qualcosa in quel rumore che non si poteva attribuire né al rimbombo né alla natura del terreno?

Answer (score 0):

Credo che in questo contesto, **fare la parte** sia una maniera un po' inusuale di dire **mettere da parte**, ovvero **non considerare**, **non tenere conto**.

> *Da parte* [...] fig., *mettere, lasciare da parte*, non tenere o non prendere in considerazione, trascurare: *da quando è cambiato il direttore, alcuni funzionarî sono stati messi da p.; metti da p. gli scrupoli, le prevenzioni, i pregiudizî; lasciamo da p. le chiacchiere, i pettegolezzi, i complimenti.*
>   <sub>Dizionario [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/parte)</sub>

Nel caso specifico del brano che hai citato, dunque, immagino che si voglia dire che il protagonista sta udendo dei passi dal suono incostante; e che ciò non pare possa essere imputato solamente al terreno non uniforme ed alla eco, ma, come viene fatto notare, probabilmente anche al fatto che la persona si sta muovendo in maniera disordinata.

> [Lo scalpiccio] era inoltre alquanto vario, fatta anche la parte al rimbombo e alla natura del terreno; quasi la persona corresse, come dire?, con una certa volubilità.

Una possibile parafrasi può essere:

*Lo scalpiccio era inoltre molto incostante, anche senza considerare la eco e la natura irregolare del terreno; quasi come se la persona corresse con un ritmo indeciso, poco uniforme.*

Comment: A mio parere, è più vicino al modo di dire "fatta la tara..."

Answer (score -1):

**Fare parte di** in "italiano moderno" significa;
"v. inf.; partecipare *a*, **Farò parte di questa gara quest'anno**, **Parteciperò** *a* **questa gara quest'anno**.

Invece, rispondendo alla tua richiesta, **fare la parte** (*fatta la parte*), significa; "v. inf.(part_n2); escludendo *...*, ciò posto *...*, **Fatta la parte di Giuseppe, iniziamo a parlare di Giovanni**, **Ciò posta** *la parte di Giuseppe*, **iniziamo a parlare di Giovanni**.

**DUNQUE**,
"fare/fatta la parte di (...)" significa "escludendo, ciò posto"; "non tenere conto di (...)".

Spero che questa mia spiegazione ti sia stata d'aiuto, ;) :).

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Potresti citare la fonte di questa definizione?

Comment: https://educalingo.com/it/dic-it/fare-la-parte

Comment: La tua citazione su Giuseppe e Giovanni viene da educalingo? Non la trovo... Vedo solo riferimenti al senso di “partecipare”, che non c'entra con questa domanda. (E poi, occhio, che educalingo assembla più o meno automaticamente parti di altri siti, a volte mettendo insieme cose che non c'entrano.)

Comment: “Escludendo” e “ciò posto” sono uno il contrario dell'altro, a pensarci bene. E infatti un'altra risposta ha mostrato che il senso di “fare la parte” è “tenere conto di”, non “non tenere conto di”.

Comment: Ho copiato da due fonti diverse ma non trovo più il link dell'altra.

Comment: @DaG: Personalmente non mi è del tutto chiaro che il senso sia "tenere conto di".

Comment: In effetti, @Charo, dai vari esempi (e forse ne potrò portare un paio d'altri) mi sto convincendo che il senso sia “fatta la parte di X” = “tenuto conto di X per scartarlo”, con un significato non lontano da quello di “fare la tara” (per calcolare il peso netto non posso semplicemente ignorare la tara; devo pesarla per poi sottrarla dal peso lordo).

Comment: @DaG: Tenuto conto di X per scartarlo o per scontarlo mi sembra più convincente.

Comment: @DaG: Non sapevo che si potesse usare "fare la tara" in senso figurato.